# Couldn't use vs code ''better comments extension'' for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

**Better comments** is an extension in **VS Code** that helps to write comments in different colors. For good readability, it is very useful. Almost all popular languages are supported. I could to use in C programming but somehow couldn't use it in Python.

comments look like in the image

[image]

Comment: What do your comments look like, currently? The image provided uses comments not in Python, but in C.

Comment: check out this answer   https://stackoverflow.com/a/77811110/10942935

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [**Better Comments** documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments), you will need to configure the colors yourself:

> This extension can be configured in User Settings or Workspace settings.

The comment highlighting doesn't automatically highlight certain comments, but *allows* you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling to figure it out but finally got it. My json setting is below. Basically 1) Avoid the first line, 2) Add "#" followed by the tag as per your settings.json file and then anything. This worked for me.

```html
 "better-comments.multilineComments": true,
    "better-comments.highlightPlainText": false,
    "better-comments.tags": [
        {
          "tag": "!!",
          "color": "#F6FF33",
          "strikethrough": false,
          "backgroundColor": "transparent"
        },
        {
          "tag": "?",
          "color": "#3498DB",
          "strikethrough": false,
          "backgroundColor": "transparent"
        },
        {
          "tag": "TODO",
          "color": "#FF8C00",
          "strikethrough": false,
          "backgroundColor": "transparent"
        },
        {
          "tag": "//",
          "color": "#68FF33",
          "strikethrough": false,
          "backgroundColor": "transparent"
        }
        {
          "tag": "**",
          "color": "#FF33EC",
          "strikethrough": false,
          "backgroundColor": "transparent"
        }
      ]
```

Comment: You are missing a comma, in the second object block

Answer (score 0):

This extension can be configured in User Settings or Workspace settings.

**"better-comments.multilineComments": true**

This setting will control whether multiline comments are styled using the annotation tags. When false, multiline comments will be presented without decoration.

**"better-comments.highlightPlainText": false**

This setting will control whether comments in a plain text file are styled using the annotation tags. When true, the tags (defaults: ! * ? //) will be detected if they're the first character on a line.

Ref: [Better Comments Doc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments)

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following code into better-comments.tags,that's enough

```
    {
      "tag": "#",
      "color": "#98C379",
      "strikethrough": false,
      "underline": false,
      "backgroundColor": "transparent",
      "bold": false,
      "italic": false
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**'Better comments' can be used for Python in VSCode .**

Check out the image shown below :

[image: Better comments in VSCode]